# Ubuntu 12.10 Network LAN issues

Tags: 12.10, networking, samba, lan

OK, so I recently started using Linux Ubuntu, and well I’ve been trying to for about a week now to LAN connect several computers at my house. But here's the issue I keep running into, 2 of the 3 computers can see each other since they have samba, yet they cannot see the third computer. And the third computer cannot see them. All of the computers have Samba, and are all on the same hub. I've been trying to troubleshoot it, but it seems a little harder than windows to fix. The OS I've been running on the computers is 2 of them have Ubuntu 12.10 and one has 12.04. One of the 12.10 and the 12.04 can see each other but the other 12.10 cannot see either one. Can anybody help?

Comment: Are all of the 3 computers using Ubuntu?

Comment: could be a firewall issue. Try turning off any firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell from the information you posted. It could be anything from a firewall issue to misconfigured samba shares.

I suggest you start by turning your firewall off on all 3 computers.

Then if the shares do not show, debug your network using ping.

If ping is working, then manually mount the shares on the command line and post any error message.

```
smbclient -L //server -U user

sudo mount -t cifs //myserver_ip_address/myshare ~/mnt -o username=samb_user,noexec
```

You have to change "server" to your server name or ip address, "user" to your actual user on the server, "myshare" to the actual share name, etc.

For details see

[Ubuntu shares not visible on the network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211705/ubuntu-shares-not-visible-on-the-network)

[How to turn on Network Discovery and Share between computers with Samba](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236746/how-to-turn-on-network-discovery-and-share-between-computers-with-samba)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is get the IP address of each machine. Ping the machine that is not showing up to make sure it is on the network. Samba uses UDP ports 137, 138 and TCP ports 139, 445. The default firewall for Ubuntu is [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/firewall.html). Hopefully all you need to do is configure firewall rules (using ufw) to allow those ports to be used.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure your 12.10 computers don't have the same host name. Then, test for basic connectivity, and work your way up to accessing the samba share. Can you ping from the problem machine to the other machines and vice versa? Once you have verified ping works, I would try running a network port scan against the problem machine from one of the other machines with nmap. On one of the other non-problem machines, hit ctrl+alt+t for the terminal, then type sudo apt-get install nmap ,hit enter and authenticate to install nmap. With the command nmap , you can run a port scan against one of the other machine's IP addresses to see if the samba ports(i.e., 139, 445) are open. I would compare the port scan of a working machine to the non-working machine to ensure they are the same. If the appropriate ports are not showing as open, check for the status of Ubuntu Firewall on the problem machine with sudo ufw status, and [make changes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) to your firewall as necessary. I don't think UFW is installed on 12.10 by default, anyway, but it's worth checking the status to see. After that, I suggest following the tips at the article below to get your samba setup correctly on the problem machine.
http://www.unixmen.com/howto-install-and-configure-samba-share-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score -1):

The way Windows shares files and printers is called SMB. The people from the SAMBA project have implemented all of Microsoft's protocols and specifications for Linux. Ubuntu therefore supports the same sort of file sharing as Windows, which is called Samba.

You can use SAMBA to share files between Linux machines. In fact, you might prefer it in case you have, for example, have a friend over with their Windows computer.

Alternatively, you can use The Linux Way of sharing files, which is NFS (Network File System) - This answer to a previous question explains how to do it. (but it's rather technical)

So, when the Sharing Options dialogue asks you to install the packages, you're not actually installing any Microsoft software or anything like that. Go ahead and do it, it's perfectly safe.

Comment: I've already installed the packages, in Linux. I'm trying to figure out why only 2 of my computers can see each other in network browsing. And why the 3rd cannot see either one of the other 2 computers, when all of the computers are on the same hub.