# "failed to retrieve share list from server: No Such File or directory" while trying to access windows shares

Tags: windows-7, samba, shared-folders

I keep getting "failed to retrieve share list from server: No Such File or directory" when I try viewing my shared files in Ubuntu 13.04 and they were all working fine until the upgrade! Help!

Comment: Have you looked at [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/74789/62483)?

Comment: Yes, I also tried the methods, no luck what-so-ever.

Comment: Mine was working fine until a few hours ago. It was working fine on 13.04 already but suddenly I started getting the error when trying to access the windows share

Answer (score 5):

Well, first install samba `smb` from package manager.
And open nautilus, choose `connect to server` from `files`. In the box that'll sow up, write your Windows machine IP in `Server` box, choose any port (21 by default) and from the drop down list that is `Public FTP` by default, choose `Windows Share`, some other input boxes will show up, but don't mind them and don't change anything, just press `connect` and there you have it.

Comment: Also worked for me, with some obvious modifications, at a two computers with Ubuntu 13.04 network, that strangely was insisting in not to work. The only difference is that in the address textbox you must enter smb://0.0.0.0 (replacing the zeros by the machine's IP). Thank you so much, Jack Mayerz.

Comment: Given a failure to be able to browse windows shares, it's certainly useful to know how to connect to a share that exists despite not being able to see it, but it's not an answer to the problem of how to get browsing of windows network shares to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note here:

> Since Ubuntu version 17.10, the minimun version of the CIFS/samba protocol has been changed for security and performance reasons. Unfortunately, that breaks the network browsing function (which requieres version 1).

Taken from a discussion in [Ubuntu Mate Forum](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/caja-browse-network-windows-network-failed-to-retrieve-share-list-from-server-no-such-file-or-directory/17400/4).

And it hasn't been fixed yet, at least on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.