# Accessing Windows 10 files from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, server, windows, files, samba

I am a novice Linux user. I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and have used Raspbian on it and have had no problems accessing my Windows 10 files shares. I wanted to try Ubuntu to see how it compares. I tried the Kbuntu version and had no luck so I switched to Ubuntu Server 20.04 and then installed Ubuntu Mate on it. Everything seemed fine. I then wanted to try the file sharing part of things and so my first step was to install Samba which seemed to go fine. However, I still cannot get to my Windows 10 file shares. I have SMB installed on the Windows machine. I keep getting the error that it "cannot retrieve file shares: connect connect to server". I have looked everywhere for a good, comprehensive set of instructions on the pieces that need to be installed, how to configure them, etc. I find bits and pieces but nothing that seems to give me the whole picture on both ends. Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74789/failed-to-retrieve-share-list-from-server-error-when-browsing-a-share-with-nau) help?

Comment: Here is how I access a Windows 10 share from Ubuntu 20.04 via `cifs`: https://askubuntu.com/a/1313854/1157519

Answer (score -1):

You have a bit of work to do if you expect to "discover" then "connect" to a Windows 10 machine from Ubuntu 20.04.

In Win10 you have to have `SMB 1.0/CIFS Server` enabled.

In Ubuntu 20.04 you have to enable SMB1 on the client side. You do that by editing /etc/samba/smb.conf and right under the workgroup = WORKGROUP line add this one:

```
client min protocol = NT1
```

*( Samba calls smb1 NT1 just to confuse people )*

You could restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart` But the best thing to do is just reboot.

*Reason: The version of Samba in Ubuntu 20.04 disables SMB1 on both the client and server side just like Win10 does. Without SMB1 there is no NetBIOS discovery or name resolution.*

The alternative is to leave Ubuntu and Win10 alone and access the Win10 machine and it's share directly using mDNS ... or by ip addresss:

In the Location bar of caja enter the mDNS network path to your Win10 machine and it's share - don't forget the .local at the end.

```
smb://win10-host-name.local/share-name
```

mDNS in Linux is called Avahi and Ubuntu server doesn't install it by default. I don't know if installing MATE over the server brings it in so just to be sure install it manually:

```
sudo apt install avahi-daemon
```

Comment: SMB1 is exploitable, you should be using SMB2 or SMB3

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here is where I am now.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Here is where I am now.  I have installed samba and suggested pieces using "sudo apt install samba". I modified the smb.conf file as suggested. I have the SMB/CIFS 1 Server enabled on Win10. I have rebooted the Ubuntu machine and Win10 box. The share on the Win10 machine is setup so that my admin account has Full Control and Everyone has Read/Write. I cannot get to it by browsing thru Caja. It sees the computer but still get the same error. I then checked and avahi-daemon was installed. I tried the smb://MACHINENAME.local/sharename . No luck. Help/

Comment: When you enter smb://MACGINENAME.local/sharename in caja you should be asked for credentials to access the Win10 share. What happens after you supply those credentials? Error message?

Comment: Guess what? when I went to reproduce the problem it is now giving me access!!!  Woo hoo!!! Thanks so much. I used the smb://.... approach again and it all seems fine.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried a lot of available guides online, and only the guide provided [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-samba-server-file-share) has worked in my situation. The crucial step for me was to open TCP ports 139 and 445 and UDP ports 137 and 138, because **smbd** and **nmbd** programs used by samba listen on these ports. The command to open ports

`sudo ufw allow samba`

Comment: Samba ist the file server, as far as I understood you want to access files from another machine (Windows). For that you need to install 'apt install smbclient'. Go for mount cifs share in Google.