# How to connect to windows network

Tags: networking

I know this has been asked before. But I am trying to connect to my Windows network.
I do not know Ubuntu very well but am learning.
My laptop is running Ubuntu 18.04.05 and my Windows computers are all Windows 10.

How do I connect to my Windows network?

Dan

Comment: Is this any helpful? https://askubuntu.com/q/1313801/1157519

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access my Windows 10 machine from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1313801/how-to-access-my-windows-10-machine-from-ubuntu)