# ubuntu 20.04 access NAS files

Tags: networking, 20.04, snap, nas

I made a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04 and I have a problem accessing my NAS files.
Everything works fine in other ubuntu 18.04 machine and no changes were made in NAS.

In ubuntu 20.04 I can browse network, I can login in NAS, and I can open files directly in any aplication. If I open a file (directly in NAS) in inkscape (for exemple), I can edit the file and save it back to its original location in NAS.

But, if I open inkscape and make a new file, I cant save it in NAS with error:
"impossible to show content" "operation not supported"

If I try to save a photo from web browser directly to NAS, I cant even "see" NAS.

Maybe it's just a small adjust in some configuration, but I simple cant discover where.

Thank you very much for your help

EDITED: I mount NAS in Files (Nautilus). I can browse and open files in Nautilus with no problem.
I open Nautilus, click in "other locations" and then put smb://servername/ then I'm able to browse content in a regular window.

EDIT 2: I'm able to save directly on NAS with "glabels" application. With web browser, inkscape, etc, I cant. It's possible to give access to these applications as well?

EDIT 3: thanks to all. The thing is, in ubuntu 18.04 everything works smooth and in 20.04 things looks harder for newbies... I bealive it's a permissions "thing"... also I have other problem: in inkscape, I cant use a extension (send to silhouette) because os error "no backend available". the extension that is normaly in /usr/share/inkscape/, is now in /snap/inkscape/8049/share/inkscape/extensions and I'm not allowed to add it in this directory. placed it in ~/.config/inkscape/extensions and it is in menu now, but dont work...

EDIT 4: Found the problem, but cant resolve it. The problem is that EVERY application installed by snap store as no permissions to access NAS.
So, my question is: is there a way to solve it? May I simple uninstall snap?

FINAL NOTE: Simple dont install applications from snap store if you want to access NAS files directly or want to add extensions or extra scripts to applications.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate how the NAS is mounted. If through `fstab` then add the relevant `fstab` line to your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newby in Linux.
I open Nautilus, click in "other locations" and then put smb://servername/
then I'm able to browse content in a regular window.

Comment: user68186 thank you for your help. But i'm able to access NAS files. The problem is that applications cant access directly. Maybe it's a permission that I must give, but dont know where or how

Comment: Looking at this conversation I interpret it like this: "Okay, as long as you use the Nautilus GUI to connect to the samba server, I don't know where to adjust what. _But if you used cifs_ instead of Nautilus, then — since a cifs mount has different controls — I would probably be able to point out what needs to be changed." Maybe I'm not right, just felt like mentioning it. (and, yet another link to mount with cifs: https://askubuntu.com/a/1313854/1157519)

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title and the answer to your question within the question. Please click the button below to answer your own question. Then after the wait click on the grey check mark ✔️ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Comment: I found [this discussion](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/access-to-nas-drive/7974) illuminating. It refers to [How to map a network drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46183/how-to-map-a-network-drive). Which in turn discusses using CIFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and a possible solution.

Simple dont install applications from snap store if you want to access NAS files directly or want to add extensions or extra scripts to applications.

That worked for me.

In ubuntu software you are able to choose the source that you want to install.