# Can't connect to NAS "Failed to retrieve share list from server. Software caused connection abort."

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing, nas

After restoring from a backup, Ubuntu 20.04 will not connect to my Ethernet router connected LG NAS. I had this problem when I first switched to Linux and solved it but I can't remember how. I thought I might have saved a file on what I did but apparently not. I looked at the suggested solutions on this site and did some web searches but nothing has worked. I tried adding the suggested strings to the smb.conf and hosts file but that didn't work. I do remember having to do something with smb.conf before but I don't remember what or whether that was to access my NAS, but I think it was. I'm seeing the message "Failed to retrieve share list from server. Software caused connection abort." How can I make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate... Have you tried this page?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/74789/failed-to-retrieve-share-list-from-server-error-when-browsing-a-share-with-nau

Comment: That was one of the pages I looked at. I edited the hosts file and smb.conf as suggested on that page. By entering the I.P address of the NAS unit into the "Connect to server" box in file manager I was able to see the folders on the NAS, but I can't open them. I now get: "Unable to access location.
Failed to mount windows share: software caused connection reset." This is a self contained, commercially sold NAS unit made by LG; not a PC being used as a NAS if it matters. I'm trying to gain access to the files and folders, not mount it as a drive (direct access to its drives is not possible).

Comment: " I'm trying to gain access to the files and folders, not mount it as a drive"
I don't get this. Accessing files and folders from a drive is exactly when you need to mount. I have the feeling you use GUI tools, and not the command line, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had posted and received a reply on another site and found it in my bookmarks. The answer is to override the default setting of the samba client and force it to use SMB1. I am now able to access the folders and files on my (apparently older) NAS.Just below the workgroup line I added

```
client min protocol = NT1
```