# Can't connect Ubuntu to Ubuntu via Samba

Tags: samba

Both laptops
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64
There is NO WINDOWS MACHINE involved.

I have Samba running on both
smbd version 4.15.13-Ubuntu started.

I turned off all security on the network to allow all traffic (for testing)

No matter which machine I'm on, if I open "Files" and select "Other Locations" under Networks I see the Samba running locally AND the one on the other laptop.  I can access the local one with no problem on either laptop. BUT....

When I try to connect to the other laptop I always get the same Message:

"Unable to access location"
"Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out"

I've tried cold starts, changing the workgroup names, etc but nothing lets me connect remotely, only locally.  Details below.

```
---- smb.conf ---------
[global]
server string = SYSTEM-1
workgroup = INVESTIGATIONS
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
name resolve order = bcast host
include = /etc/samba/shares.conf
```

```
------ shares.conf ------------------
[Uploads]
path = /share/Uploads
force user = smbuser
force group = smbgroup
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
writeable = yes

[Downloads]
path = /share/Downloads
force user = smbuser
force group = smbgroup
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
writeable = no
```

Comment: Could it be a `ufw` problem? Try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1138007/149708

Comment: If system-1 is the host name of this server from the client machine connect to it with `nautilus smb://system-1.local/uploads`. Does that work?